# Pipenv creation using python

Tags: python, pipenv, virtual-environment

Is there a way to create virtual environment using python code. It would be great help if anyone can help. I need to automate creating virtual environment.As in using subprocesses or something similar

pip3 install pipenv
cd /root_directory_of_project
pipenv shell

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Yup a lot..but could get any good solution. Hence asked here

Comment: Then wouldn’t it be better to ask about those attempts?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install pipenv
cd /root_directory_of_project
pipenv shell
```

if you want to see what modules are installed do,

```
pip3 freeze
```

do this inside the pipenv shell.
use **exit** to exit the pipenv shell.
Anytime you want to use the virtual environment just do, **pipenv shell** in that directory to enter the shell again.

Comment: might want to include `pip3 freeze` somewhere in there to show which modules are installed in case more need to be added in the `requirements.txt` :)

Comment: is that what you meant? you can edit my answer and put that in there. I will approve